# Uri not Absolute exception getting while calling Restful Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, http, servlets, cas

The below code snippet is using to call my web service using restful API.

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    String uri= "https://127.0.0.1:8443/cas-server-webapp-3.5.0/login";
    WebResource resource = client.resource(URLEncoder.encode(uri));
      MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
       queryParams.add("username", "suresh");
       queryParams.add("password", "suresh");
       resource.queryParams(queryParams); 
       ClientResponse response = resource.type(
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").get(ClientResponse.class);
    String en = response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(en);
```

And getting this exception while running the above code

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute

    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:151)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
```

I googled many articles and did'nt get where i am doing wrong .

Side note :`cas-server-webapp-3.5.0`  war deployed on my machine in Apache tomacat7

Comment: In ur **URI**, are you sure, its **https**, and not **http**? Please check that once.

Comment: Yes its HTTPS only . SSL enabled on my Tomcat server .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An absolute URI specifies a scheme; a URI that is not absolute is said to be relative.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

So, perhaps your URLEncoder isn't working as you're expecting (the https bit)?

```
    URLEncoder.encode(uri)
```

Answer (score 14):

For others who landed in this error and it's not 100% related to the OP question, please check that you are passing the value and it is not null in case of spring-boot: @Value annotation.

Comment: also make sure you don't forget ${} around the name of the property in your @Value annotation :)

Answer (score 9):

The problem is likely that you are calling URLEncoder.encode() on something that already is a URI.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem only in your IDE encoding settings. Try to set UTF-8 everywhere:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In an API Key Authorization Scenario...

You may be performing the 2nd REST call after getting an AUTH_TOKEN and ENDPOINT_URL from the first REST call.

Check your concatenation of "<ENDPOINT_URL> + <API_METHOD_URI>", you may be sending only the API_METHOD_URI.

This happened to me using the Streamsets integration platform trying to connect to Oracle's Responsys API.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was getting this error, when configuation in yaml files, which composed my URL was changed. oops,